# Docbook / XML restrictions for ID / IDREF

Tags: xml, docbook

In my (generated) docbook files I got an ID / IDREF pair that started with a number (say `015_code` with the attributes xml:id / linkend and consequently a warning was emitted (XMLMind in this case):

`bad value for attribute "id" from namespace "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"`

In the book "XML in a nutshell" I read:

> ID numbers are tricky because a number is not an XML name and therefor
>   not a legal XML ID. The normal solution prefixes the values with an
>   underscore or common letter.

This solution works for me, but when looking at my example `015_code` this is not a number so my questions:

- is my interpretation / quote incorrect and it be that an ID / IDREF cannot start with a digit
- is this possible a bug in XMLMind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first bullet point is correct; ID/IDREF can’t start with a number.  The value must be a valid [Name](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name)...

```
Names and Tokens

[4]   NameStartChar ::=   ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
[4a]  NameChar      ::=   NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]
[5]   Name          ::=   NameStartChar (NameChar)*
[6]   Names         ::=   Name (#x20 Name)*
[7]   Nmtoken       ::=   (NameChar)+
[8]   Nmtokens      ::=   Nmtoken (#x20 Nmtoken)*
```

From https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-attribute-types ...

> Validity constraint: ID
>
> **Values of type ID must match the Name production.** A name must not
> appear more than once in an XML document as a value of this type;
> i.e., ID values must uniquely identify the elements which bear them.

and

> Validity constraint: IDREF
>
> **Values of type IDREF must match the Name production, and values of**
> **type IDREFS must match Names**; each Name must match the value of an ID
> attribute on some element in the XML document; i.e. IDREF values must
> match the value of some ID attribute.

Comment: The link to `Name` is the missing link, maybe you can add that part of the text (Names and Tokens) to the answer.

Comment: @albert - yeah I planned on adding that the next time I’m on my computer. It’s a pain with my phone.